# Kubernetes :: Run POD on node without GPU

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, nvidia

I'm using Kubernetes to orchestrate my micro-services.

In my K8S cluster, I have CPU-Only instances and other instances with GPU.

I would like to know how could I force specific PODS to run on the instances without GPU?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [explained here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#example-use-cases) you can use taints and tolerations to ensure that some pods will not be scheduled on nodes with GPUs.

All nodes with GPU can be tainted like this:

```
kubectl taint nodes <nodename> hasgpu=true:NoSchedule
```

Now add the following to specs of pods - which need GPU. This will ensure that any pod which does not have this toleration will not go to an instance with GPU attached.

```
tolerations:
- key: "hasgpu"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "true"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

You can check out a detailed explanation and examples of taints and toleration [in this blog](http://blog.infracloud.io/advanced-scheduling-kubernetes/)

Though adding the toleration in YAML file is not as much clean and you can use an admission controller to dynamically add tolerations using an admission controller. This will add tolerations to pods which request specific resources such as GPU. You can [find more details here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#extendedresourcetoleration), this solution is elegant but relatively more work.

Comment: What if I want to force a pod to use cpu on a GPU node? Is it possible?

Comment: @GioGio - I think it should be possible. When you are requesting resources - you request CPU/GPU